# Error SQL SERVER "IF..ELSE"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que intento hacer es que con base a una tabla que contiene información de productos edite otra en especifico que moneda se estará usando

```
DECLARE @curcnt INT = 0;
WHILE @curcnt < (SELECT CONVERT(int, (SELECT MAX (id_del_product) FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1]))+1)
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT id_currency FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1] = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [db2].[dbo].[tabla2]
        SET MONEDA = 'Pesos' 
        WHERE id_producto = @curcnt;
        SET @curcnt = @curcnt + 1;
    END
END
```

**db1 > tabla1**

```
    +-------------------------------------+
    | id_currency | Columna 2 | Columna 3 |
    +-------------------------------------+
    | (INT) 0     |           |           |
    | (INT) 1     |           |           |
    | (INT) 0     |           |           |
    | (INT) 2     |           |           |
    +-------------------------------------+
```

**db2 > tabla2**

```
    +-------------------------------------------+
    | MONEDA            | Columna 2 | Columna 3 |
    +-------------------+-----------+-----------+
    | (CHAR) Dolares    |           |           |
    | (CHAR) Pesos      |           |           |
    | (CHAR) Dolares    |           |           |
    | (CHAR) Dorales    |           |           |
    +-------------------------------------------+
```

Lo que intento es que si en la ***base de datos 1*** en la ***tabla 1*** el valor ***id_currency*** es igual a "1" se actualice la ***base de datos 2***, ***tabla 2***, ***columna "MONEDA"*** a "pesos". Pero me muestra error:

```
    Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 server "" Line 7
    Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba cambiando `IF(SELECT id_currency FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1] = 1)` que sea `IF(ISNULL((SELECT id_currency FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1]), 0) = 1)`; aunque veo te hace falta `WHERE` que garantice devolver 1 solo valor o por lo menos en vez de `id_currency` que sea un `COUNT(*)` bueno, esto conforme la lógica con que valides.

Comment: Que tal!. Intente `IF(ISNULL((SELECT id_currency FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1]), 0) = 1)`, pero me da error. En cuanto a `WHERE` para eso es el while, según yo para que sea cada row, con `count(*)` en realidad no cuento el numero de filas sino el resultado de la consulta, ya que `id_currency` devuelve `1 si es pesos`, `0 si es dólares` o `2 si también es dólares`. En realidad no se porque me da error en la consulta.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. ¿Cual es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Prueba con `IF EXISTS(SELECT id_currency FROM [db1].[dbo].[tabla1] WHERE  id_currency  = 1)`